# Matplotlib: How to plot grid boxes colored by number

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, weather

I have a file with the following data

```
0018.00 -083.00 45
0018.00 -082.00 55
0018.00 -081.00 15
0019.00 -100.00 25
0019.00 -099.00 45
0019.00 -098.00 05
0019.00 -086.00 25
0019.00 -085.00 25
0019.00 -084.00 35
0019.00 -083.00 45
```

The first column contains the y values.
 The second column contains the x values. 
The third column contains the z values.
I would like to assign a color to each z value and plot gridboxes of this dataset.

For instance

```
05=Brown
15=Red
25=Green
35=Blue
45=Purple
55=Orange
```

It will look similar to the following image 
![enter image description here][1]

I have tried looking at the mathplotlib thumbnails, but they seem to only work with random datasets.

What code should I use to plot my columned data?
So far, I have tried the following code

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cm = plt.cm.get_cmap('RdYlBu')

var = numpy.loadtxt('map.csv')

y = var[:, 0:1]
x = var[:, 1:2]
colors = var[:, 2:3]

plt.scatter(x, y, colors, cmap=cm)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Could you post the actual code instead of the screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`imshow`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow)

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

content = numpy.loadtxt('map.csv', delimiter=',')

# here you would have to create a "grid"
# where each value in content would be "binned" to the correct position,
# creating the array named "bins"

plt.imshow(bins, 
           interpolation='nearest',
           cmap=plt.cm.RdYlBu,
           extent=[xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax])  ## you should be able to figure these out
```

Comment: I got "IOError: Failed to interpret file 'map.csv' as a pickle"

Comment: Sorry, the correct function is `numpy.loadtxt`, I corrected it. Another similar, more powerful function is `numpy.genfromtxt`.

Answer (score 1):

While the approach you've shown using `scatter` does work, it takes a little bit of tweaking to get things to look right. Here's a stab at it:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# unpack columns from map.csv into x y and z variables.
y, x, z = np.loadtxt('map.csv').T

ax = plt.subplot(111, aspect='equal')
ax.scatter(x, y, c=z, marker='s', s=160, lw=0, cmap='RdYlBu')
plt.show()
```

Notice that I've played with the marker shape (`marker='s'`) and size (`s=160`), as well as specified that the `z` values are to be used as the color (`c=z`).

However, as you've noticed, `scatter` isn't designed to show a regular grid like what you're really looking for. You'd be better off going with `imshow` or one of the `pcolor` variants like @heltonbiker suggests.